# I need hepl with spliting a string

Tags: python, for-loop, problem-spring

I have a problem with python It is really easy but I still can find a solution for that:

I have a string. I split it. I have a for cycle

```
string = "Super best good string"
temp = string.split()
for finished_string in temp:
   number = 0
   finished_string.append(temp[number])
   number += 1
```

The out of this should be:
"Super+best+good+string+"

but This solution must be good for a different length of string with 2 words or 3 words

Comment: `new_string = string.replace(' ', '+')+'+'`

Comment: For one thing, you're re-initializing `number=0` at the start of each loop, so it will never increment. For another, `finished_string` is a new variable local to the loop. If you want to append something, append it to a list or string that exists _outside_ the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "Super best good string"
temp = string.split()
new_string = ""
for finished_string in temp:
    new_string += finished_string + "+"
```

Comment: Using `finished_string = "+".join(temp) + "+"` removes the need for the for loop which seems cleaner.

Comment: Depending on how you want your code to look, `"+".join(temp) + "+" is shorthand, using a for loop is longer but easier to read, so it depends on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work for a few reasons, like `finished_string.append(temp[number])` is appending something to itself in effect.

Instead use this:

```
string = "Super best good string"
finished_string = "+".join(string.split()) + "+"
print(finished_string)
```